# what is the problem in this line n & h& H & w& $〖\Delta{DATA}〗_{TP}$\\ \hline

Tags: equations

After I run latex  forbidden sign appear

```
 n & h& H & w& $〖\Delta{DATA}〗_{TP}$\\ \hline
```

what is the problem in this line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you give us a compilable code that reproduce the error? It is hard to guess what is wrong with only one line of code.

Comment: Also, could you copy and paste the error message?  I'm not sure what you mean by "forbidden sign".

Comment: @Teepeemm -- On my screen, there are very faint lenticular brackets (Unicode 3016 and 3017) wrapped around the element starting with `\Delta`.  I can't find them in the comprehensive symbols list and detexify doesn't find them.  I suspect they aren't readily found in "western" fonts, but I have seen them in a printed Japanese dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

- Sorry, your question is not clear, so I just guessi ...

  - in your code line is missing one `\` ...it should be terminated by `\\`, i.e. that you have a typo in this code line fragment (meanwhile in question title it is written correct).
  - you not load `unicode-mat` package and than use `XeLaTex˙or` LuaLaTeX`` engine
- To be sure, what is your problem, you should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document beginning with ˙\documentclass`and end with`\end{document`) which reproduce your problem.
- For example the following MWE works fine:

```
% LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
n & h& H & w& $〖\Delta{DATA}〗_{TP}$ \\ \hline % <---
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the missing backslash was just due to code not being correctly marked in the question.

Comment: @campa, that can be. But till now OP problem can not be verified or confirmed. Probably we should close question us "Needs details or clarity"...

Comment: I agree. Maybe before closing just a ping in comments that a complete code is needed...